# Firebase push promise never resolves

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save an object from my React Native App.  Please look at the below code snippet.

```
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
    .push({ name, phone, shift })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Save to Firebase was successful');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

But in the Firebase console, I don't see anything. I am surprised that the then and catch don't even get called. What am I missing? The console does not show any error.

My Firebase DB Rules:

[image: My Firebase DB Rules]

Here's my Firebase realtime DB view:

[image: Firebase realtime DB view]

Question- I am pushing to `/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees` path, do I need to manually create 'users' node?

Comment: Did you call initialize your app with your firebase credential? Something looks like this in your `App.js` file: `firebase.initializeApp(config)`

Comment: Yup, took care of that inside the componentWillMount() callback in App.js. Firebase auth is working fine.

Comment: What about database rules? Maybe your operation is rejected due to the database rules you wrote and you somehow silenced the warnings in your app?

Comment: Does your console show _"Save to Firebase was successful"_?

Comment: I added the Firebase DB rules in my original post. The promise never resolves, I don't see 'Save to Firebase was successful' or the error log.

Comment: GitHub link: https://github.com/kunal-jaggi/react-native-manager/blob/master/src/actions/EmployeeActions.js

Comment: Are you seeing any of the logs show up? Like the ones outside the Promise?

Comment: One thought: isn't it because push returns firebase.database.ThenableReference? BTW, you didn't tell us if the database is updated. The console doesn't show anything but is the DB updated?

Answer (score 3):

In Firebase push() function genrates a unique key for each new child, and set() or update() functions insert or update data in node.

Try this:

```
  firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
    .push()
    .set({ name, phone, shift })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Save to Firebase was successful');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Or this:

```
 let niceKey =  firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`).push()

niceKey.set({ name, phone, shift })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Save to Firebase was successful');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use push to save data to Firebase, instead use `set` or `update`. Here's how it works:-

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`).set({
    name: name,
    phone: phone,
    shift : shift
});
```

For more info visit:- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Hope it'll help.